# How to run RUnit tests in the same file?

Tags: r

Is it possible to define R Unit tests in the same file as the code under test and then run the tests when the file is executed?

```
sum <- function(x, y) {
  return(x + y)
}
test.sum = function() {
  checkEquals(2, sum(1, 1))
}
```

Comment: I would think so. Have you tried it?

Comment: Your code does exactly that, if you add a call to `test.sum()` after the definition.

Comment: "When the file is executed" ?  Why did it get the death penalty?   More seriously, RUnit (just like other unit test frameworks) use a test runner function to _find the files with tests_ and then _run the function matching the name regexp_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Execution is the penalty for using RUnit instead of testthat.

Comment: In my experience with other languages, it's possible to write a file that includes its own tests without having to go through the additional step of creating a set of tests in a suite. @Spacedman's answer was spot on. In fact, I've just dropped the wrapper function altogether, and everything works as expected.

Comment: This would be a bad idea in a package - your tests would run every time a user loads your package. Convention is to put tests in separate files in a "tests" folder in your package. There might be hacky ways of attaching tests to the function, maybe as an attribute or in a text comment block, but you'll have to write the mechanism for it unless its in CRAN already...

Comment: This isn't for a package: it's for an RMarkdown analysis where I'd like to write a few sanity checks.